# Algorithm For Continued Fraction of $\pi$ without error.

Tags: algorithms, continued-fractions

Is there an algorithm that will output the numbers in the continued fraction of $\pi$ without error? If one uses the usual method of calculating continued fractions, an approximation of $\pi$ is required, eventually causing errors. The algorithm should be able to work on computers with limited precision. The method would probably have to use the natural properties of $\pi$ that separate it from its approximations.

Comment: There's a theorem that if $|\alpha - p/q| < 1/(2q^2)$ then $p/q$ is one of the continued fraction convergents to $\alpha$, and moreover at least one of any pair of consecutive continued fraction convergents to $\alpha$ will satisfy this inequality.  So take your favorite decimal approximation to $\alpha$, compute the continued fraction convergents of that approximation, and check if they approximate $\alpha$ within $1/(2q^2)$. If they do, you've got a convergent for $\alpha$ itself. Eventually it'll stop working, and then take a better decimal approximation and repeat.

Comment: Okay, I think that is the best answer possible. Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Wait actually. If you are using an approximation of $\pi$ to begin with, how do you check it it approximates it within $1/(2q^2)$?

Comment: I assume you are able to figure out if two real numbers are within a particular distance from each other! The use of a cont. fraction expansion of an approximation to $\pi$ in order to extract rigorously the initial part of the c.f. expansion of $\pi$ itself depends on the ability to check numbers are with $\varepsilon$ of each other for varying choices of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Umm. How would one check is $\pi$ (exactly) and another rational number are within a certain distance. Again, subtraction by itself would not work since we are dealing with approximations of $\pi$.

Comment: Use rational approximations to $\pi$ from above and below that are close to each other. Then another number is no further from $\pi$ than its larger distance from either the upper or lower rational approximation.

Comment: Okay. That is easy. Thank you. (No I just need to figure out how to have arbitrary precision, but that is not a math problem.)